# ExpressionEngine on MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, mamp, expressionengine

I am trying to run a legacy 1.6.8 EE install on MAMP. I can see the index page but the expression engine tags are rendered to the browser rather than being parsed and running DB queries. I'm also not seeing any styling (images, css etc) on the front end or in the control panel.

In addition, I cannot install a fresh version of 1.6.8 as I get the error:

Error: Unable to perform the SQL queries needed to install this program. Please make sure your MySQL account has the proper GRANT privileges: CREATE, DROP, ALTER, INSERT, and DELETE

I do this as root which has the relevant privileges. I have tried switching off MYSQL STRICT mode (both in my.cnf and by running SET @@global.sql_mode= '';

Does anyone know what might be causing either of these problems? I have already tried official [EE support](http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/201469/)

Comment: Like Mark says in the forum thread, the database issue sounds like it's more to do with your MAMP setup than EE. Can you run any other database-driven applications on your local setup?

As for the lack of styling in the control panel, sounds like your theme path might be set incorrectly.

Comment: I am running Wordpress fine on the same MAMP install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing **ExpressionEngine 1.x** on any version of **MAMP 1.9.5** or later is a [known-issue](http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/183482/#868657), and causes the following error during the EE installation process:

> Error: Unable to perform the SQL queries needed to install this
>   program. Please make sure your MySQL account has the proper GRANT
>   privileges: CREATE, DROP, ALTER, INSERT, and DELETE

Unfortunately, the error message isn't indicative of the actual problem, as `'root@localhost'` has full MySQL privileges.

**The solution is to downgrade to MAMP v1.9.4** ([162 MB Download](http://mamp.mac-devedge.de/downloads/MAMP-PRO/releases/1.9.4/MAMP_MAMP_PRO_1.9.4.dmg.zip)).

MAMP v1.9.5 *(released 2011-03-11)* upgraded MySQL from v5.1.44 to v5.5.9, which according to EllisLab is problematic with EE 1.x — all versions of EE 2.x do not have this problem.

Comment: Instead of using MAMP I used a spare windows machine with legacy PHP and MySQL add-ons in Wampserver. I was then able to run the legacy EE instance successfully